# How to increase/even polygon count on stretched areas

Tags: sculpting, polycount

When I make a humanoid head shape, and then I try to make two horns come out of it, polygons are stretched and they create bad shapes. My question is simple:

How do I make so that I increase the polygon count in the stretched horns to the number of polygons that I have in the head-shape?

I am asking this because essentially it happens to me a lot when I try to make a nose, or ears, or anything else, the low poly count makes it difficult to work with and I can't mould properly and certain parts cease to be malleable.

I don't want to use subdivision as it affects everything. I just want to make my 'poly count' on the stretched parts even to the rest of the mesh/shape.

Here is a video for reference (watch only from minute 12:25 to 12:40):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5ixOZMDOhc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable *Dyntopo* (dynamic topology) in your brush options:

[image]

This will locally adapt the mesh detail when you touch the area with your brush.

Note: this will likely break some kind of object data (vertex groups, shape keys, UV maps) so it should be used only when doing the initial sculpting of your model. [More from the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tool_settings/dyntopo.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I needed to know :)